# Google Identity Platform password hashing algorithm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hash, cryptography, identity, kdf

Is anyone able to confirm what is the hashing algorithm used by the Google Identity Platform to store passwords? There is a [considerable argument](https://cryptobook.nakov.com/mac-and-key-derivation/password-encryption) that a secure KDF like Argon2 be used, however seemingly the documentation does not state how passwords are stored (apologies if I have not found the right place in the docs). The GCP [documentation on migrating users from an existing app](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/migrating-users) includes many pre-existing options, some of them rather insecure (e.g. MD5, SHA) which is notably not a Google Identity Problem but rather one of the application where the users are migrating from, yet there seems to be no information what happens after the migration. Thanks a lot in advance!